# Получить нужные результат из строки или number

Tags: javascript

Есть к примеру числа `13121313176781` и `1537275`. В первом числе нужно получить `6` и `81` так как разделитель `7`, а во втором числе нужно получить `2` и `5`. 
Не силен в RegExp, помогите пожалуйста. Пока выходит такое.

```js
var number1 = 13121313176781;
var number2 = 1537275;

function getNumbers(number) {
  console.log(number.toString().match(/7[^d+]/g))
}
getNumbers(number1)
getNumbers(number2)
```

Comment: по какому алгоритму вы разделитель определяете?

Comment: @ThisMan, не по какому, разделитель всегда один 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var number1 = 13121313176781;
var number2 = 1537275;

function getNumbers(number) {
  console.log(number.toString().split('7').slice(-2))
}
getNumbers(number1)
getNumbers(number2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция **`split()`** не помогает? Если разделитель 7, то у вас в каждой строке получается 3 участка, а не 2.

```js
var v1 = '13121313176781';
var v2 = '1537275';

var result_1 = v1.split('7');
var result_2 = v2.split('7');

console.log(result_1); // 131213131, 6, 81
console.log(result_2); // 153, 2, 5
```

Comment: Почему автору не нужна первая часть - это, в принципе, дело автора. Главное чтобы в ответе был `[6, 81]`, а не `[131213131, 6, 81]`

Comment: Желательно получить только последние два значения

Comment: Так, что мешает взять result_1[1] и result_1[2] ? Задача расплывчитая, и без понимания "почему не нужен первый участок" не решить его верно. Может завтра будет не 3 участка а 10? Что именно будет нужно автору? Все кроме первого участка или только последние 2 участка? Это в корне меняет логику.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const v1 = '13121313176781';
const v2 = '1537275';
const v3 = '13475435713457071';

// tail - задает кол-во элемент с конца, которые вернет функция
const splitNumber = (str, tail = 2) => {
   const result = str.split('7');
   return result.splice(result.length - tail);
}

console.log(splitNumber(v1));
console.log(splitNumber(v2, 1));
console.log(splitNumber(v3, 3));
```

Comment: Во втором случае с `1537275` по условию должно быть `[2,5]`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko посмотрите еще раз код, есть переменная `tail`, которая отвечает за кол-во выводимых элементов. Во втором вызове я передал 1, по умолчанию 2

Comment: Спасибо. Не обратил внимания на параметр `tail`.